# ExecutorService#awaitTermination blocks forever - broken / special on GAE?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

GAE just blocks forever when I try to terminate an `ExecutorService`. Small sample below:

```
ThreadFactory threadFactory = ThreadManager.currentRequestThreadFactory();
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(threadFactory);

Future<String> future = pool.submit(new Callable<String>() {
    public String call() throws Exception {
        return "Hello from Thread";
    }
});

LOG.info("Result is: [" + future.get() + "]. Pool expected to be idle now");
pool.shutdown();
if (!pool.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
    LOG.info("Pool does not like shutdown()");
    pool.shutdownNow();
    if (!pool.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
        LOG.info("Pool does not even like shutdownNow()");
    }
}
```

The same code works without blocking when running locally, it just blocks without terminating when running deployed on AppEngine. The timeout can be increased until the 60 second request limit forces the code to interrupt.

This seems to be a subtle yet dangerous difference to a standard JVM. Code found regularly to clean up can essentially kill your service. [`ThreadManager` documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/ThreadManager#createThreadForCurrentRequest%28java.lang.Runnable%29) mentions that the threads are a bit special but they are -as far as I understand - interruptible and meant to terminate.

- Is it just me (some library messing with threads)?
- Is it a bug / feature / somewhere documented?

Since waiting for termination is just pointless, is it okay to just call `pool.shutdown()`, then assume all is going to be okay? Running threads are a good way to leak memory..

---

#### Update #1

I'm even more confused after some more testing. All works fine when using a `Thread` directly. Slightly convoluted example:

```
final CountDownLatch threadEnter = new CountDownLatch(1);
final Object wait4Interrupt = new Object();

Runnable task = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        synchronized (wait4Interrupt) {
            threadEnter.countDown();
            try {
                wait4Interrupt.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // expected to happen since nothing is going to notify()
                LOG.info("Thread got interrupted.");
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
};

Thread thread = ThreadManager.createThreadForCurrentRequest(task);
// not started state
LOG.info("Thread log #1: " + thread + " " + thread.getState());
thread.start();

threadEnter.await();
// thread is inside synchronized / already waiting
synchronized (wait4Interrupt) {
    // => guaranteed that thread is in waiting state here
    LOG.info("Thread log #2: " + thread + " " + thread.getState());
    thread.interrupt();
}

thread.join(1000);
// thread is dead
LOG.info("Thread log #3: " + thread + " " + thread.getState());
```

Logs produced:

```
I 16:08:37.213 Thread log #1: Thread[Thread-7,5,Request #0] NEW
I 16:08:37.216 Thread log #2: Thread[Thread-7,5,Request #0] WAITING
I 16:08:37.216 Thread got interrupted.
I 16:08:37.217 Thread log #3: Thread[Thread-7,5,] TERMINATED
```

The thread returned by the factory isn't started, it supports wait & interrupt just fine and it can be join()'d and is terminated afterwards. What else would an `ExecutorService` want to do?

---

#### Update #2

`pool.toString()` from example #1 after `shutdown()` results in

```
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@175434a
    [Shutting down, pool size = 1, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
```

which also indicates that it's not an issue caused by unterminated threads since it states `active threads = 0`.

---

#### Update #3

Pools do shutdown nicely when being told to do so *before* they finished their task. The following terminates correctly after 500 ms. Adding `future.get()` will show the original problem again.

```
Future<String> future = pool.submit(new Callable<String>() {
    public String call() throws Exception {
        // sleep a bit so pool is "busy" when we're trying to shutdown.
        Thread.sleep(500);
        return "Hello from Thread";
    }
});
// get here = evil
pool.shutdown();
pool.awaitTermination(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

=> Issue seems to occur on idle pools only. Busy pool can be shutdown.

Comment: this is still happening (Q1 - 2016)

Answer (score 2):

You are right, `Thread`s on App Engine are interruptible. Quoting from the [official docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/):

> An application can perform operations against the current thread, such as `thread.interrupt()`.

Since it is working fine locally, it is a difference between the development server and the sandbox at production environment.

I think the development server allows multi-threaded execution if not disabled while the production environment requires to explicitly state it in the [application config file (`appengine-web.xml`)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig):

```
<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
```

Unless you explicitly state your app is thread-safe, serving a request can only use 1 thread therefore your `ExecutorService` cannot start a new `Thread` to execute the task you submitted and therefore `future.get()` will block. It would block until the "current" thread would end but obviously that could only happen after serving the request, so you have a deadlock here.

Comment: The `<threadsafe>` flag enables concurrent requests. Concurrency within 1 request should always work. I also have `<threadsafe>` enabled so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Awarded you the full bounty, you would have gotten just half of it otherwise :) The correct answer is probably going to be "it's a bug on appengine" - I will probably self-answer this once I know for sure.